# Can't deploy parachute

Tags: just-cause-2

After a long-ish playthrough of Just Cause 2 on PS3 (about 20+ hours, completed the story, about 35% completion) my parachute won't open. Ever. I press the X button (jump/parachute) and nothing happens, even when in free fall (jumping out of a plane/helicopter) or grappling. No matter what I do, I can't open my parachute.

I've reverted my controller settings to default (and ALL settings, just to be sure). The Controls screen still shows X as the control for parachute. Doesn't work, ever. I've restarted the game, the system, no luck. Saved, loaded the save (not from autosave). I tried switching from the default parachute to the red DLC parachute. Nothing has worked. The parachute does work on a new save, and on a much older save.

Is there anything I can do to get my parachute back? The game is completely unplayable without it. If this glitch is permanent, how can I avoid it if I have to go back to the old save?

Comment: that stinks, the parachute is like 90% of the fun in JC2

Comment: Maybe you ran out of parachutes? :D (kidding)

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue, which happened right after I completed the "Pirate Broadcast" mission for the "Reapers". On [this forum](http://forums.eidosgames.com/showthread.php?t=106961), I found out about [this fix (direct link to patch download)](http://mod.gib.me/justcause2/tools/FixParachute.zip), and applying it on my ".sav" file corrected the problem.

Comment: Crap, I'm on PS3. Fix sounds great for PC users though.

Comment: Oh I missed that in your question, sorry that it can't apply to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- Entering a cutscene, for example entering a mission/stronghold takeover.
- Deleting the Just Cause 2 Entry in Game Data Utility (NOT save games!)

Comment: Nope, tried both, still no parachute...

Comment: Have you tried dying/respawning?